# Python (in VS code) can't recognize modules have been installed

Tags: python, module, visual-studio-code

All was good until I start to change the "launch.json" file for some other issues. However, I made it the same as before:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {"name":"Python: Current File","type":"python","request":"launch","program":"${file}","console":"integratedTerminal"},

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

after that when I run my code, the first several lines to import module, e.g. import pandas as pd,
then it shows me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'.
but if I try to import in Jupyter, no issue at all.

Not sure if I should uninstall VScode or something. Thanks for any advice!

- reply to myself, I haven't figured out yet, but I think it's related to the python path.

Comment: Have you verified the correct python interpreter is selected in vs code?

Comment: Hi, John. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out [ask] to include more information in your question and structure it in a clear and concise way. I will be happy to help if you can include some short code to run, and you explain the problem in few words.